# Complex electric field in second order polarization

Tags: electric-fields, polarization, complex-numbers, non-linear-optics

I am reading an introductory article on nonlinear optics. Here is what the part that's troubling me says:

$$\tilde E(t) = Ee^{-i\omega t} + \text{c.c} $$

When this electric field is incident on a material with non-zero value of $\chi^{(2)}$, it induces a second order polarization given by:

$$ \tilde P^{(2)}(t) = \epsilon_0  \chi^{(2)} (Ee^{-i\omega t} + \text{c.c})^2$$

$$ \tilde P^{(2)}(t) = \epsilon_0  \chi^{(2)} (E^2e^{-2i\omega t} + E^{*2}e^{2i\omega t} + 2EE^*)$$

I am not sure what $E^*$ is. Wasn't the whole point of writing the first equation to leave $E$ as a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

$E^*$ is the complex conjugate of the E-field amplitude. The author has not included a phase term with the time dependence, so it must be bundled with the amplitude prefactor.

Answer (score 0):

If the complex amplitude $E$ corresponds to the real time varying field intensity $\mathcal {E}(t)=C(t)cos(\omega t)+S(t)sin(\omega t)$ then the complex conjugate $E^*$ corresponds to $\bar {\mathcal {E}}(t)=C(t)cos(\omega t)-S(t)sin(\omega t)$ where $C(t)$ and $S(t)$ are slowly changing amplitudes of the respective sinusoids. Slowly here means that $\big|\frac{1}{C}\frac {dC}{dt}\big|,\big|\frac{1}{S}\frac {dS}{dt}\big| \ll \omega$.

Comment: Were you supposed to have an $i$ before each sine term?

Comment: $\mathcal E$ is the honest-to-goodness true physically "real time function" measurable field intensity. etc., not a mathematically "complex" one, it has no $\mathfrak {j}$ in it. But $E=\Re{[\mathcal {E} e^{\mathfrak {j}\omega t}]}$